# Build list when select option change

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the full list that have the same id that matches with the select option. But I can't figure out how to get the id from the attribute by using the name to be able to filter it.

The html example:

```
<select id='groopy' onchange='see();'>
    <option>default</option>
    <option>lista1</option>
    <option>list1</option>
 </select> 
 <ul id='grupo'>
    <li id='list1' name="lista">Playground (Rangbhoomi)</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">Empire Made Me</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">Transmission</li>
    <li id='lista1' name="lista">Hostel Room 131</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">A Disobedient Girl</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">Travels in the Land of Kubilai Khan</li>
    <li id='list1' name="lista">The Indian Mutiny</li>
    <li id='lista1' name="lista">Beauty and Sadness</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">The Collaborator</li>
    <li id='list1' name="lista">I, Lalla</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">No Full Stops in India</li>
    <li id='lista1' name="lista">For Lust of Knowing</li>
    <li id='default' name="lista">On the Road to Kandahar</li>
</ul>
```

And the script I'm trying:

```
<script>
    function see(){
        var listita = document.getElementById('groopy').options[document.getElementById('groopy').selectedIndex].value;

        var items = document.getElementsByName("lista");
        var items_id = document.getElementsByName("lista").getAttribute('id');

        if(listita==items_id){

                    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                        { 
                        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = items[i].outerHTML;
                        }

            }
    }
    onload= see();

</script>
```

By the way, the select and the ul are generated dynamically so I don't actually now the id's that could be provided. I'm trying a little different approach [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TpJkZ/) .

When I manage to make the select filter work, the for stop working. WHY? I'm going crazy with this. Please help!!

Comment: First thing first things first . `ID` is supposed to be unique.. replace that with class names instead

Comment: Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/5X3B5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are having **multiple elements with same id's** which is wrong.. Cause **getElementbyId** will only fetch the first element encountered by it.

Replace then with **class instead**

Next you are overwriting the **HTML** for every iteration, so you will always have the last item appended to it.

Instead store that in a variable and append it after the for loop.

you need to bind your element with a `change event`, otherwise your call only works once when the page loads for the first time.

Try this

```
// Cache the selector as you are using it multiple times
var dropdown = document.getElementById('groopy');

function see() {
     // set the selected option
     var listita = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value
        items = document.getElementsByClassName(listita);
        html = '';
    // For each item with class name, iterate over it and store in a string
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         if (items[i].className == listita) {
            console.log((items[i].outerHTML));
             html += items[i].outerHTML
        }
    }
    // set the html after the for loop
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = html;
}
onload = see();

// attach the change event handler
dropdown.addEventListener('change', see);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/TpJkZ/19/)**

Comment: Man thanks!!! The explanation you made make all the sence in the world. I'm learning and some times is hard.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the id's to class in the li tags and use this function...

```
function see(){
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById('groopy').options[document.getElementById('groopy').selectedIndex]. value;                
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedVal);
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    { 
        html += items[i].outerHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = html;

}
onload= see();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1** - Change `id` to `class`

**Step2** - Traverse DOM elements with jQuery class selector. In this way replace `document.getElementId('id)` with `$('.className')`